# 'makecert' is not recognized as an internal or external command in command prompt

Tags: cmd, makecert

For creating certificate run this command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=effectLabs Server" -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2020 -sky exchange C:\myCerts\ELServer.cer -sv C:\myCerts\ELServer.pvk
```

Following error occurred in command prompt:

> 'makecert' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use the Visual Studio command prompt to use the makecert utility on the command line.

Answer (score 24):

On **Windows 10**, this tool has been renamed to the **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015**. You can find this by simply pressing the Windows key, and then searching for 'Developer Command Prompt'.

Comment: This Answer was the fix for me. Make sure to run as Administrator.

Comment: I am using Developer Command Prompt for VS2017, but still getting "'makecert' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"

Comment: @rakesh-kumar I am eexperiencing the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: @Aaron, my issue is resolved when i installed windows SDK.

Answer (score 5):

On windows 10, I came across with the same issue. In spite of running my Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 as administrator, I got the same error. But when I installed [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) then makecert command successfully got run.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **Visual Studio command prompt**.

You can find it in:

**In Windows 8**
On the Start screen, press the Windows logo key **Windows logo + Z**. (To open the Start screen, press the Windows logo key Windows logo on your keyboard.)
Choose the **Apps view** icon at the bottom of the screen and then **press V**. The list will include all installed Visual Studio command prompts.
Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want to use).

**In Windows 7**
Choose Start, expand **All Programs**, and then expand **Microsoft Visual Studio**.
Depending on the version of Visual Studio you have installed, choose **Visual Studio Tools**, Visual Studio Command Prompt, or the command prompt you want to use.

Comment: still getting the error: `makecert is not recognized as ... `

Answer (score 1):

for anyone still still getting this error even after installing the mentioned above SDK, make sure to include the path to the `makecert` file in the system env path, which should be along the lines of : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin`