# create both Server and Client certificates

Tags: c#, wcf

i have install the Windows Development  tools in Program Files.On the Developer command in Visual studio 2015 i have created the server and client certificate they got error'make-cert is not recognized' what should i do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['makecert' is not recognized as an internal or external command in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981766/makecert-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-promp)

Comment: MakeCert is deprecated. To create self-signed certificates, use the Powershell Cmdlet New-SelfSignedCertificate.On Windows 10, this tool has been renamed to the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015. You need to open it as an administrator.